# How to solve the gradient of a matrix function

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let:

$$A=\hat{r}+e^{j\theta}$$

Where $\hat{r}, e^{j\theta} \in \mathbb{C}^n$, and j = (-1)^(.5). Set $L \in \mathbb{R}^{n \ x \ n}$, define $S$:

$$S=A^TLA$$

The gradient of $S$ is given by (general formula):

$$\nabla  S = \frac{\partial S}{\partial r}\hat{R}+ \frac{\partial S}{\partial \theta}\hat{\theta}$$

I need to find a expression of $\nabla S$ in terms of the other variables.

My idea is:

$$\nabla S = LA \frac{\partial A}{\partial r}+LA \frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta}$$
$$= L(\hat{r}+e^{j\theta})1+L(\hat{r}+e^{j\theta})je^{j\theta} $$

However, the dimension of the second term seems wrong?

How to solve this gradient problem?

Comment: I have no idea what you're even asking :S

Comment: r is a vector [r1...rn], e^(jq) is also a vector = [e^(jq1)...e^(jqn). q = theta

Comment: Is $\times$ the cross product then?

Comment: Just matrix times vector: R^(n*n)*R^(n*1) = R^(n*1). L is a square symmetric matrix.

Comment: I would spend some time typing up the question if you want someone to understand you. I have no idea what you want to show, and your "idea" doesn't make sense. Maybe you're just missing chain rule or something though.

Comment: Now some order is done, first what is $j$?

Comment: And what is the relationship between the $\hat{r}$ in the first equation and in the third?

Comment: Well if j is the imaginary unit then $e^{j\theta}$ is really a element of $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @sleevechen we are ok now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First $S$ is a scalar for sake of the exercise (because the notation is very blurry) I'm not going to expand the expression for $A$.

As you said:

$$\nabla S=\frac{\partial S}{\partial r}\hat{r}+\frac{\partial S}{\partial \theta}\hat{\theta}$$
$$\nabla S=\frac{\partial A^T L A}{\partial r}\hat{r}+\frac{\partial A^T L A}{\partial \theta}\hat{\theta}$$

You can note that $A^T L A$ is the next:
$$A^T L A =\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n l_{ij}a_i a_j$$
Where $a_i$ is the component $i$ of the vector $A$ and $l_ij$ is the component $i,j$ of $L$. So the derivative with respect to $r$ is:
$$\frac{\partial A^T L A}{\partial r}=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n l_{ij}\left(\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial r} a_j +a_i\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial r}   \right)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n l_{ij}\left(\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial r} a_j \right)+\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n l_{ij} \left(a_i\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial r} \right)$$
$$=\frac{\partial A^T}{\partial r}LA+AL\frac{\partial A}{\partial r}=2AL\frac{\partial A}{\partial r}$$
The last equality is due the symmetry of the first summand with the second: 
$$\left(\frac{\partial A^T}{\partial r}LA\right)^T=A^T L^T  \left(\frac{\partial A^T}{\partial r}\right)^T=A^T L \frac{\partial A}{\partial r}$$
Analogous is:
$$\frac{\partial A^T L A}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial A^T}{\partial \theta}LA+AL\frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta}=2AL\frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta}$$

In both cases as you will probably noted $\frac{\partial A}{\partial r}$  and $\frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta}$ denote the derivative of the vector at each component with respect to $r$ and $\theta$ respectively.

Finally the gradient is:

$$\nabla S=2A^TL\frac{\partial   A}{\partial r}\hat{r}+2A^T L\frac{\partial A}{\partial \theta}\hat{\theta}$$

Now keeping in mind what is $A$ for you is a matter of replacement.